# How to retain ISO 8601 date format in RequestParams when using SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring, datetime, spring-boot, java-8

I have the following method which accepts two date parameters in ISO 8601 format. However, when I print these dates I am losing the seconds, milliseconds and the timezone 'Z'. How do I retain the entire date even if the seconds and milliseconds are 0?

```
            @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/status")
                public StatusObject getStatus(@RequestParam("id") String id, 
                                                     @RequestParam("startTime")@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime startTime,
                                                     @RequestParam("endTime")@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime endTime) throws Exception{

                    StatusObject statusObject = null;

                    System.out.println("startTime: "+ startTime);
                    System.out.println("endTime: "+ endTime);

                    return statusObject;

            }
```

**Input :  http://localhost:8080/status?id=123&startTime=2018-05-03T15:00:00.000Z&endTime=2018-05-03T18:00:00.000Z**

**Output:** 
startTime: 2018-05-03T15:00
  endTime: 2018-05-03T18:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, if you use parameters containing `seconds=0` and `milliseconds=0` (`HH:mm:00.000`), `LocalDateTime` will only output as `HH:mm`

If you want to save `TimeZone` values, you should use `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime` does not support this.

Comment: The correct class to use would be `OffsetDateTime` since `Z` is an offset, not a time zone (even though it is also referred to as “Zulu time zone”; yes, it’s confusing).

Comment: Ole V.V. Thanks for letting me know about this

Comment: Thanks, @DoTrungDuc  and OleV.V. ZonedDateTime works, I will give OffsetDateTime a try

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the milliseconds: http://localhost:8080/status?id=123&startTime=2018-05-03T15:00:00.957Z&endTime=2018-05-03T18:00:00.555Z

It appears to be ignored when zero milliseconds are informed.

**My output**:
startTime: 2018-05-03T15:00:00.957
endTime: 2018-05-03T18:00:00.555